# Добавление модели в БД Laravel периодически занимает много времени

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu, php-fpm

Периодически в логах сервера проскакивают такие запросы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Т.е. периодически скорость ответа сервера начинает увеличиваться с 0.2 с до 3 или даже 8 секунд. Это происходит рандомно и не зависит от нагрузки на сервер или времени суток.
В логах медленных запросов php-fpm эти моменты выглядят вот так:

```
[30-Oct-2020 09:13:46]  [pool www] pid 5494
script_filename = /public/index.php
[0x00007f53c441f0a0] execute() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:459
[0x00007f53c441f010] Illuminate\Database\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:658
[0x00007f53c441ef50] runQueryCallback() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:625
[0x00007f53c441ee90] run() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:460
[0x00007f53c441ee10] statement() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:412
[0x00007f53c441ed90] insert() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php:32
[0x00007f53c441ece0] processInsertGetId() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2658
[0x00007f53c441ec30] insertGetId() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:1317
[0x00007f53c441eb60] __call() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:839
[0x00007f53c441eab0] insertAndSetId() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:804
[0x00007f53c441ea20] performInsert() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:667
[0x00007f53c441e970] save() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:749
[0x00007f53c441e910] Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:424
[0x00007f53c441e890] tap() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:750
[0x00007f53c441e810] create() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:23
[0x00007f53c441e730] forwardCallTo() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1618
[0x00007f53c441e6a0] __call() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1630
[0x00007f53c441e610] __callStatic() /app/Models/SkillRequest.php:102
[0x00007f53c441e540] send() /app/Http/Controllers/Skills/GameSearchController.php:294
[0x00007f53c441e400] index() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
```

Участок долгого скрипта, на который указывает лог SkillRequest.php:102 в GameSearchController.php:294 - это всего лишь навсего добавление экземпляра модели в БД базовой функцией Laravel:

```
SkillRequest::create($skill_request);
```

Сама модель:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'skill_id',
    'user_id',
    'type',
    'request_content',
    'response_content',
  ];

  protected $casts = [
    'request_content' => 'array',
    'response_content' => 'array',
  ];
```

Структура миграции:

```
Schema::create('skill_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('skill_id', 255);
            $table->string('user_id', 255);
            $table->string('type')->default(NULL);
            $table->json('request_content')->default(NULL);
            $table->json('response_content')->default(NULL);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

В логе медленных запросах mysql по этому поводу пусто.
Задач данного скрипта - ведением логов, и скрипт заупскается при каждом запросе, но в одних случаях он отрабатывает хорошо, а в других плохо :( В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Продолжайте копать, это мало чего говорит. Может там есть подписка на events, в которых после создания происходит что-то. Шерстите весь код.

Comment: Здесь было бы не плохо смотреть метрики на сервере. Загрузка проца, диска, сети. Посмотреть какие фоновые обработчики запускаются по крону.